# What's wrong with this method of populating RecyclerView with database table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Before I wrote the codes below, I searched here on SO on how to populate recyclerview with database table. All the answers I came across were virtually saying the same thing "RecyclerView doesn't have CursorAdapter like listview. Write an adpater that extends [CursorRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59#file-cursorrecyclerviewadapter-java) etc"

However, I found out that by iterating the cursor and putting the data in an array, I was able to populate recyclerview from database like I do with json and html data.

So these are my codes:

**BookItem**

```
public class BookItem {
    private String title;
    private String imageUrl;


    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**BookAdapter**

```
public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    List<BookItem> mBookItems;

    public BookAdapter(List<BookItem> bookItems, Context context) {
        mBookItems = bookItems;
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.book_item, parent, false);
        return  new BookViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        BookItem bookItem = mBookItems.get(position);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleyRequest.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(bookItem.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(((BookViewHolder) holder).thumbNail,
                R.drawable.shop_book_thumb, R.drawable.shop_book_thumb), 120, 120, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        ((BookViewHolder) holder).thumbNail.setImageUrl(bookItem.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        ((BookViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(bookItem.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBookItems.size();
    }

    public class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.book_item_thumb) NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        @BindView(R.id.book_item_title) TextView mTitle;

        public BookViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

}
```

**Part of BookFragment**

```
private void getBookDb () {
        Log.d(TAG, "getBookDb called");
        mDatabase = mBookHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + BookEntry.NAME, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                BookItem bookItem = new BookItem();
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookEntry.TITLE));
                String imageUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookEntry.IMAGE_URL));

                bookItem.setTitle(title);
                bookItem.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

                mBookItems.add(bookItem);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Database is empty");
            emptyDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        mDatabase.close();
        mBookAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mBookAdapter.getItemCount());
}
```

In my eyes, it's working perfectly, but then I am only a beginner.

So, please what is wrong with this implementation and what's the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is wrong with this implementation

You are doing database I/O on the main application thread, in your `getBookDb()` method. Do not do I/O on the main application thread, please.

In general, there is nothing particularly wrong with converting a `Cursor` into a `List` of some sort of POJO. Similarly, there is nothing particularly wrong with converting JSON into a `List` of some sort of POJO. However, ideally, you only do that sort of conversion if you are getting something useful out of it. You don't *have* to do that conversion just to use a `Cursor` in a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please can you expatiate on this: *However, ideally, you only do that sort of conversion if you are getting something useful out of it. You don't have to do that conversion just to use a Cursor in aRecyclerView* ?

Comment: @Ozuf: There is no need to convert a `Cursor` into anything else just to use it in a `RecyclerView`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList), where I get a `Cursor` from `MediaStore` and wrap that in a `RecyclerView` without conversions. Converting a `Cursor` to POJOs takes time and heap space. So, only do that when it is clearly a benefit. Just showing the results in a `RecyclerView`, IMHO, is not enough of a benefit.

Comment: I noticed that you in the sample app,  you didn't close the cursor. Please is this intentional? If yes, why?

Comment: @Ozuf: "Please is this intentional?" -- when using the `Loader` framework, the `Loader` is responsible for releasing what it allocates. In this case, `CursorLoader` is responsible for closing the `Cursor`.

Comment: Ok but I am a bit confused. Since I am not using a `CursorLoader`, where is the right place to release the cursor?

Comment: @Ozuf: You would close the `Cursor` when you are done with it. For example, you would close it when you are swapping in a fresh `Cursor`, or because you are done with this `RecyclerView.Adapter` entirely.